# React Query cannot invalidate queries after closing confirm dialog

Tags: reactjs, react-query

```
const handleMutationSuccess = {
    onSuccess: async (result) => {
      await queryClient.invalidateQueries("deleted_projects");
      toast({
        containerStyle: {marginBottom: "40px"},
        title: result.data.message,
        status: result.data.success ? "success" : "error",
        duration: 2000,
        isClosable: false,
      });


    },
  };

  const mutation = useMutation(deleteProject, handleMutationSuccess);

  const projectUndelete = (id) => {

    if (window.confirm("Do you want to restore this project?")) {
      mutation.mutate({project_id: id});
    }
  };
```

I cannot invalidate queries after confirm dialog closing.
I believe following is the reason for this:

After I click OK or close the confirm dialog, window focus event triggers refetch, before even mutation is finsihed.

When the mutation is done, I try to invalidate "deleted_projects", react query does not invalidate the "deleted_projects", because it was just refetched.

As a result, I will see the old results on page, which is not correct.
Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your analysis is spot on. Two issues here:

1. `invalidateQueries` will not "do anything" if a refetch is already in progress. If you want `invalidateQueries` to cancel ongoing refetches and start a new one, you have to pass `cancelRefetch: true` as options. See the [api docs here](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/QueryClient#queryclientinvalidatequeries).

It is also worth noticing that we have changed this behaviour for v4, the next major version, which is currently in beta. We believe that calling `invalidateQueries` imperatively should, per default, cancel refetches and trigger a new one, to avoid the pitfall you have just described. The flag still exists if someone wants to opt out of that behaviour. Have a look at the https://react-query-beta.tanstack.com/guides/migrating-to-react-query-4#consistent-behavior-for-cancelrefetch

2. browser apis like `alert` or `confirm` open another window, so there will be a focus event once that dialog closes. If your query is stale, there will be a refetch. We have an [issue here](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query/issues/2868) that describes some workarounds. Probably the best would be to *not* use those functions, but you can also tinker with the `focusMananger` of react-query to temporarily disable that behaviour.

Comment: I passed cancelRefetch:true to the invalidateQueries, and this solved the issue. Thank you for the detailed info.